# Regular expression stop capture group at ? symbol

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to capture `"thing1"` and `"thing2"` in these strings:

```
http://www.example.com/stuff1/thing1   
http://www.example.com/stuff2/thing2?id=9999
```

In python, I tried this:

```
re.findall('^.*(?:stuff1/|stuff2/)(.*)\??.*$', url)
```

The first example URL works with my code, but the second gives:

```
['thing2?id=9999']
```

I was intending for the capture group to not include the `"?"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just capture "non `?`" chars:

```
re.findall('^.*(?:stuff1/|stuff2/)([^?]*).*$', url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
re.findall('^.*(?:stuff\d\/)(.*?)(?=\?|$).*$', url)
```

In this regex, I used Positive Lookahead `(?= )` to exclude `?`

Comment: Thank you, your use of ? swaps the lookup in the capture group from greedy to lazy, which seems to be key here. I selected another answer because it was simper

Comment: @AlexG No worries, I'm glad you found a working solution.